# How to convert binary files context into int/long value in C++

Tags: c++, binary, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I am storing a value in a binary file with fstream. The value is unsigned short type.

```
unsigned shord value=1750; //2 byte variable
file.write((char*)&value,sizeof(value));
```

My problem is that I want to read this binary file in another function, but it gives me some weird symbols (Obviously because it is binary).
Is there any way to get those two bytes and convert them to my old value (1750) ?

Here's what I have tried:

```
cout <<(unsigned short)(unsigned char)(s2[8]);//s2 variable where the whole body is stored
cout <<(unsigned short)(char*)(s2[8]);
```

I have tried other things, too, but they were just chickenscratch and aren't worth including here.

Comment: Are you reading those values using `file.read((char*)&value,sizeof(value));` accordingly?

Comment: Don't use C-style casts in C++.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? hey παντα ρει i am greek too. can you give me a personal mail to contact you?

Comment: @Dionisis I mean don't do casts like this: `(char*)&value` in C++. The correct C++ cast there is `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value)`. C++ has many different cast operations, and a C-style cast can mean *any of them* which can have disastrous consequences if it uses a different cast type then you were expecting.

Comment: You are right but i dont think this solve my problem. My problem is while reading the file and convert the binary to number

Comment: One possibility is that the reading is wrong. Please do what @πάντα ῥεῖ told you and show the code where you are reading the value. Also, why are you writing a short integer pointer as char pointer ? that's probably the problem, because that can cause little/big endian problems. The types have different sizes. Substitute the (char *) cast by reinterpret_cast<short int*>(&value) and tell us what happend.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I doubt the problem is caused by endianess, unless the file was produced on a different machine, with a different architecture.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ thought about it. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might do it (note uses C++11 features):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void write_shorts(string filename, vector<unsigned short> shorts)
{
    ofstream f;

    f.open(filename, ofstream::trunc|ofstream::binary);

    for(auto s: shorts)
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s), sizeof(s));
}

auto read_shorts(string filename)
{
    ifstream f(filename);
    vector<unsigned short> res;
    short x;

    while(f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x)))
        res.push_back(x);

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    // Write 3 shorts to a file
    write_shorts("myshorts", {4711, 1, 0xffff});

    // Read them back into a vector
    auto v = read_shorts("myshorts");

    cout << "Read " << v.size() << "shorts: " << endl;

    for(auto x: v)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```